# ODBC Driver and client authentication for DB2 9.7

Tags: db2

I have an IBM DB2 database (version 9.7) which uses client authentication.

I'm trying to create an connection from my computer to this database with an ODBC driver, so I've downloaded the last odbc driver (for version 9.7) from IBM website and when I want to configure the authentication it only allows me to chose this :

[image]

Does anyone knows if it exists an odbc driver which allows client authentication ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that you need to install either Runtime Client or Data Server Client package to enable client authentication for ODBC/CLI.

Comment: And once installed, you need to catalog the remote instance and database.

Comment: I've installed Runtime Client and catalogged the remote instance and database. So now I can connect from the command line tools, it works. I've added my ODBC driver using the database alias created when I've catalogged the database but when I open this driver and click on connect I get this error : "SQL1013N The database alias name or database name "" could not be found". I have nothing on the advanced settings and if I try to add a new CLI Parameter, it will not be saved.

Comment: I've try this time with Data Server Client package and it works ! thanks